# Adding background gradient with vendor prefixes via jquery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to add the following background gradients

```
$('.colorshiftdots:nth-child(1) .colorshiftfilter').each(function() {
  var styles = {        
    'background': '-webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(rgba(' + backgroundcolor + ', 1)), color-stop(55%, rgba(' + backgroundcolor + ', .13)), color-stop(70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)))',
    'background': '-o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(' + backgroundcolor + ', 1) 0%, rgba(' + backgroundcolor + ', .13) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%)',
    'background': 'linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(' + backgroundcolor + ', 1) 0%, rgba(' + backgroundcolor + ', .13) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%)',
    'opacity': '1'
  };

  $(this).css(styles);
});
```

The problem is that only the last one gets applied as the property is all the same.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted the code doesn't work because your `styles` object cannot have three different entries for the same property (here 'background') - so the `styles` object actually only consists of the last line. That is why you get the 'linear-gradient' when you call `.css(styles)`.

To implement vendor-specific CSS code jQuery offer **cssHooks** http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/

However you may also try to just use the standard definition (i.e. last line) and see whether jQuery dynamically outputs vendor-specific code when it runs on Safari or Opera (that's kind of the point of jQuery).